# Fourier series for exponential function

Tags: fourier-series

Fourier series for function $f(x)=c^x$, $c\in\mathbb Z$, $c>1$ on interval $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b$.

Can I use the next formulas for this case?:
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left[a_n\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{l}\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{l}\right)\right],$$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{l}\int\limits_a^bf(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{l}\right)dx,$$
$$b_n=\frac{1}{l}\int\limits_a^bf(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{l}\right)dx,$$
where $l=(b-a)/2$.

Particularly I need a Fourier series for function $f(x)=2^x$ on interval $(0;1)$.

Comment: Find this theorem in your textbook.  See what properties of $f$ are required for the formula.  Does $c^x$ satisfy those properties?  (In particular, the formula fails at the endpoints $a,b$ of your interval.)

Comment: Thanks. I've found the properties, the main difficulty for me was non-periodicity of my function and the interval other than $(-\pi;\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of interest where

$$f(x)=2^x\tag{1}$$

the corresponding Fourier series is

$$\tilde{f}(x)=\frac{1}{\log (2)}+\underset{K\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^K \left(\frac{\log(4)}{4 \pi^2 n^2+\log^2(2)}\, \cos(2 \pi n x)-\frac{4 \pi n}{4 \pi^2 n^2+\log^2(2)}\, \sin(2 \pi n x)\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

which is valid on the interval $0<x<1$.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (2) for $\tilde{f}(x)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $f(x)=2^x$ where formula (2) is evaluated at $K=100$.

[image: Illustration of formula (2) in orange overlaid on formula (1) in blue]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (2) for $\tilde{f}(x)$ in orange overlaid on $f(x)=2^x$ in blue

Comment: Thanks! I've obtained the same result using my formulas, so those formulas seem to be correct. I just wasn't sure about them.

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case you proposed, you can perfectly use the written formulas. But, for your particular case (2^x, 0<x<1), since the representation can possibly be odd, I'd recommend you to use the formulas that just involve the sine (they're the easiest ones to calculate).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to use the cosine, obtained the Fourier series and plotted the graphs, it fits. I'll try the sine, too.

Comment: The "sine method" works well too!